# Array not getting the value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the code below to get the value assigned to Array "UIDList()". But for what ever reason it is only getting the last value only. Can you please correct what could've been gone wrong.

```
Dim strTest As String
Dim strarray() As String
Dim UIDList() As String
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim TotUID As Integer

Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Pro\test.txt")
txtpro = oFS.ReadAll

strTest = txtpro
strarray = Split(strTest, "=")

For intCount = LBound(strarray()) To UBound(strarray())
    If InStr(strarray(intCount), "NAME") Then
       UIDList() = Split(strarray(intCount), "NAME")
     End If
Next

For TotUID = LBound(UIDList()) To UBound(UIDList())
Debug.Print UIDList(TotUID)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improper nesting:

change to this:

```
For intCount = LBound(strarray()) To UBound(strarray())
    'Erase the array
     Erase UIDList
    If InStr(strarray(intCount), "NAME") Then
       UIDList() = Split(strarray(intCount), "NAME")
     End If

'/ Check if UIDList() has any elements
 If Not (Not UIDList()) Then
    For TotUID = LBound(UIDList()) To UBound(UIDList())
       Debug.Print UIDList(TotUID)
    Next
 End If   
Next
```

Comment: Getting "Script out of range" error at line For TotUID = LBound(UIDList()) To UBound(UIDList())

Comment: You need to check if the array is initialized. See the updated answer.

Comment: It works, but keeps printing the same data until it finds the next value. I just wanted to print it once for each new value fine.

Comment: Thank You both of you. It works the way it supposed to.

Comment: @cyboashu I feel that OP should use option explicit so that All variables are declared. For example oFSO has not been declared and also no reference to Scripting run time library. for experienced persons, no problem but for a newbie it may cause trouble in testing the program while learning. Since you are checking a lot of posts, I wish to have your observation on my view point.

Comment: Totally agreed, using `Option Explicit` is always a good idea. No harm what so ever and helps you to catch syntax errors as you type.